# Diophantine equations and number theory

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

> If $x$, $y$ and $z$ are integers, then prove that $$x^2+y^2-z^2=1997$$ has infinitely many integer solutions.

Answer (score 1):

If you begin with a solution with $x,y,z > 0,$ you can get solutions with larger and larger entries from
$$  (x,y,z) \mapsto (2x+y+2z, \; \; x + 2y + 2z, \; \; 2x+2y+3z)  $$

```
jagy@phobeusjunior:~$ ./homothety_indef 1 1 -1 0 0 0  1 1 -1 0 0 0  3


Sat Mar 18 12:21:06 PDT 2017

====================================...............

      2     -1      2 transposed        2      1      2
      1     -2      2 transposed       -1     -2     -2
      2     -2      3 transposed        2      2      3

      2      1     -2 transposed        2      1      2
      1      2     -2 transposed        1      2      2
      2      2     -3 transposed       -2     -2     -3

      2      1      2 transposed        2      1      2
      1      2      2 transposed        1      2      2
      2      2      3 transposed        2      2      3



             -4 :     1     1         -1      0    0    0
             -4 :     1     1         -1      0    0    0


-4 =  -1 * 2^2
-4 =  -1 * 2^2
Sat Mar 18 12:21:06 PDT 2017


jagy@phobeusjunior:~$
```

Comment: Sorry if it's obvious, but could you include a derivation of how you obtain those extra solutions?

Comment: @mrnovice given square three by three matrices $A,B$ that are symmetric with integer entries, I wrote a program that gives solutions $P$ to $P^T A P = B.$ When $A,B$ are indefinite, I also tell the computer a bound on the absolute values of entries of $P.$ In this case I solved $P^T A P = A.$

Comment: Oh okay, so would it be difficult to solve by hand then?

Comment: @mrnovice not exactly, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_of_primitive_Pythagorean_triples   I ought to add that it may not be so easy to find all solutions of the given problem with 1997 and prove that you have them.